# Postgres Streaming Replication lagging, using lots of CPU and little I/O

Tags: postgresql, replication

We have 2 dedicated DB Servers. One is master and other is its streaming slave.
Postgres version **9.0.17**.

We have similar hardware on both servers and using 15krpm SAS drive in Raid 10 for Database cluster. The only difference is that on server we have 128 GB ram and on slave we have 64 GB ram.

The issue which we are facing is that our streaming slave is lagging behind.

On the streaming slave we have

```
postgres=# select pg_last_xlog_receive_location();
 pg_last_xlog_receive_location
-------------------------------
 1F7D/DD3BA000


postgres=# select pg_last_xlog_replay_location();
 pg_last_xlog_replay_location
------------------------------
 1F75/5BE08980
```

This difference between wal received and replay is increasing constantly.

Please let me know that how this issue can be resolved.

Output of `perf top -u postgres` is

```
98.30%  postgres          (.) DropRelFileNodeBuffers
0.20%  postgres          (.) 0x000000000008b05b
0.14%  (kernel)          (k) copy_user_generic_string
0.13%  postgres          (.) hash_seq_search
0.07%  postgres          (.) hash_search_with_hash_value
0.05%  (kernel)          (k) _spin_lock
0.05%  (kernel)          (k) apic_timer_interrupt
0.03%  (kernel)          (k) do_timer
0.03%  postgres          (.) RememberFsyncRequest
0.03%  (kernel)          (k) __sb_start_write
0.02%  (jbd2)            (k) do_get_write_access
0.02%  (kernel)          (k) unroll_tree_refs
0.02%  (cciss)           (k) do_cciss_request
0.02%  (ext4)            (k) ext4_check_dir_entry
0.02%  (kernel)          (k) path_walk
0.02%  (kernel)          (k) scheduler_tick
0.02%  postgres          (.) LWLockAcquire
0.02%  (kernel)          (k) dyntick_save_progress_counter
0.02%  (kernel)          (k) _spin_lock_irqsave
0.02%  (kernel)          (k) audit_syscall_entry
0.02%  (ext4)            (k) ext4_journal_start_sb
0.02%  (kernel)          (k) radix_tree_range_tag_if_tagged
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) sys_getppid
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) native_read_tsc
0.01%  libc-2.12.so      (.) _IO_str_init_static_internal
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) __getblk
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) run_timer_softirq
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) system_call
0.01%  postgres          (.) __errno_location@plt
0.01%  libc-2.12.so      (.) __GI___libc_lseek64
0.01%  postgres          (.) XLogReadBufferExtended
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) memcpy
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) irq_work_run
0.01%  postgres          (.) fsm_set_avail
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) kmem_cache_free
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) do_unlinkat
0.01%  libc-2.12.so      (.) vfprintf
0.01%  postgres          (.) hash_any
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) sysret_check
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) mutex_lock
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) printk_tick
0.01%  postgres          (.) elog_start
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) __percpu_counter_add
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) file_update_time
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) enqueue_task_fair
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) blk_recount_segments
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) rcu_check_callbacks
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) put_pid
0.01%  postgres          (.) mdunlink
0.01%  postgres          (.) LWLockRelease
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) current_kernel_time
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) perf_event_task_tick
0.01%  (kernel)          (k) native_apic_mem_write
```

output of gdb for postgres startup process

```
(gdb) thread apply all backtrace Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fd06d28f7c0 (LWP 26949)):
#0  0x00000000005ec320 in DropRelFileNodeBuffers ()
#1  0x0000000000603115 in smgrdounlink ()
#2  0x000000000047d992 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000048eca9 in StartupXLOG ()
#4  0x0000000000490c58 in StartupProcessMain ()
#5  0x00000000004a6faf in AuxiliaryProcessMain ()
#6  0x00000000005d31c3 in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000005d7372 in PostmasterMain ()
#8  0x000000000057e320 in main ()
```

Comment: So what is the network and disk I/O on both? There's no way we can tell what your machines are doing, is there?

Comment: There is no issue with network speed as I can see that all the wal files are transferred from master to slave. There is not much IO wait on slave. System load average is around 1. If I look into the details of postgres startup process, it is consuming from 99.1% to 99.9% of CPU and wait% is just 0.0% to 0.1%. I am wondering what this postgres startup process is doing as it is recovering wal files at really slow rate.
On Master, the load average is staying around 1 to 3. We are not having any issue with master. It is the backup which is not catching up.

Comment: `perf top -u postgres` might tell you more about what it's doing. Is `iotop` showing much activity on the replica? Is there anything informative in `dmesg`?

Comment: OK, that's an interesting one. What's your `shared_buffers` set to? And how many tables do you have, vaguely? Do you `CREATE` and `DROP`, `CLUSTER` or `TRUNCATE` lots of tables/sequences/etc  in normal production operation? Do lots of `REINDEX`es?

Answer (score 9):

Current (true at least in PostgreSQL 9.4 and older) PostgreSQL releases have single-threaded WAL recovery.

This means that replay of the write-ahead log occurs in only one recovery worker, and is thus able to benefit less from I/O concurrency than a normal running master. This can result in WAL replay lagging behind in cases where the replica and master have similar hardware, even when you'd expect the master (which is generally also under more load) to be the slower server.

(It'd be  great to improve this, but wanted it enough to do the work yet, and nobody seems keen to fund it at the moment).

That said, your case with very high CPU use doesn't seem to fit with issues of low I/O concurrency. In your situation I'd be attaching `gdb` and seeing what the replay proess was doing, or using `perf top` to examine what the system as a whole is up to, then dig deeper with `perf` once I had some clues. I'd also be looking closely at `iotop`, `vmstat`, `iostat`, the PostgreSQL logs, `dmesg`, etc.

### After investigation

Profiles revealed that most time was being spent in `DropRelFileNodeBuffers`.

That does a linear scan through `shared_buffers` whenever a relfilenode is deleted - caused by `truncate`, `drop table`, `cluster`, `drop index`, etc. This must be done during WAL replay, as well as on the main node.

So this suggests that:

- Your `shared_buffers` is probably very big; and
- You're probably doing lots of operations that delete relfilenodes

Reducing `shared_buffers` on the replica may well help.

Comment: There are no errors in dmesg as well as postgres logs. In iotop the writing of postgress is staying between 200Kb/s to 600Kb/s (combined of postgress startup and wal writer process). The disk is however capable of very high writing speed. Even if I will do a bonnie++ run with the runing slave, bonnie++ is writing at speed of around 450Mb/s. I am unable to figure out any thing from perf top. Its output is attached for you reference.

Comment: 98.46%  postgres             [.] DropRelFileNodeBuffers
  0.20%  postgres             [.] 0x000000000008b05b
  0.09%  postgres             [.] hash_seq_search
  0.08%  postgres             [.] hash_search_with_hash_value
  0.04%  [kernel]             [k] do_timer
  0.03%  [kernel]             [k] apic_timer_interrupt

  0.02%  postgres             [.] LWLockAcquire
  0.02%  postgres             [.] hash_any
  0.02%  [kernel]             [k] native_write_msr_safe

Comment: 450MB/s sequential I/O doesn't mean 450MB/s random I/O - on RAID 5 systems I've seen incredibly awful random I/O results. But this is RAID 10 so it should be OK. You'll need to look at what it's doing while it hammers away at the CPU - gdb, perf, etc.

Comment: Ugh, things like that are unreadable in comments. Edit question, comment when edited. (include command as well as results).

Comment: Are there any postgres configuration settings which can affect the restoration speed?

Comment: Not really, no. OS options possibly, but that's very OS/filesystem dependent. It's weird for Pg restore to be CPU bound, so I don't think this is simply restore not keeping up, there's more to it than that. You need to find out where it's spending the CPU time.

Comment: Output of perf top -u postgres is edited in question.

Comment: Can anyone derive from perf and gdb output that whats wrong with postgres startup process and why it is talking too much time to recover / replay wal files?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. Someone pointed out that reducing the shared buffer can help. It was set to 12 GB. I changed it to 1 GB. After that I can see the postgres startup is utilizing alot of resources in iotop. Previously it was writing in few hundred KB/s but now it is varying from 2 MB/s to 30 MB/s. Postgres startup process cpu utilization which was around 99.9% has dropped as well.

The lag which was increasing by 50 wals per hour is now reducing by 200 per hour. So our backup will soon catch up with master.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked you what `shared_buffers` was set to, once I saw the profiles...

Comment: Thank you for your help. The backup has now catch up with master and is working fine.